# Choice Group behavior - select element upon hover in J2ME polish

Tags: user-interface, java-me, midp, j2mepolish

The current implementation of ChoiceGroup (view-type: verticalfixed) has three states: unselected, hover, selected. When using this component on a phone with a keypad, UP and DOWN key events hover the individual choice group elements and FIRE would actually select the element.

Is there a way in which I can modify this behavior so that hover == selection ?

Comment: Could you listen to actual key input and manage what is select programatically yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Use getselectedIndex under FIRE. Hover is just css.  //#style hoverChoicegroup

for css

```
.hoverChoicegroup{

}

.hoverChoicegroup:hover{

}
```